# Is there any way to check Sqflite Database tables in flutter using Device File Explorer in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, sqflite

I am creating database in Flutter using `Sqflite` my database is created successfully and tables also I can print data on command line but I want to know how can I see all the tables using database file like Native Android ?

Comment: if you want to access the database, you can use `flutter_stetho` package from pub.dev. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stetho

Comment: @Xuzan can I save database file like native android using file explorer?

Comment: @Xuzan it is not working for me.

Comment: what do you mean by save database like native android? can you explain please?

Comment: When I create local database a database file is created inapp file storage we can save it and open to see all the data.

Comment: there is already device file explorer  option at the side of the android studio (bottom right in my case), by navigating to data>data>your_package_name>databases , there will be database created with extension .db . You can save it and see its data. Is it what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Sqflite writes its data by default from the app's internal directory as demonstrated on the [docs](https://pub.dev/packages/external_path). Calling `getDatabasesPath()` returns the default database directory on Android, the same goes on iOS. To access this folder, you can navigate to the device's storage in `/data/{app.package.name}/`